# Assigning String to Array is Returning Nil - Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

When web scraping my forum in swift I can run the following code to print in console the titles of each forum topic:

```
enum HTMLError: Error {
    case badInnerHTML
}
class DiscussionBoardResponse {
    init(_ innerHTML: Any?) throws {
    guard let htmlString = innerHTML as? String else { throw HTMLError.badInnerHTML }
        let doc = try SwiftSoup.parse(htmlString)
        let titles = try doc.getElementsByClass("Forum_NormalBold").array()
        var nestedLoginController: LoginController!
        for i in 0..<titles.count {
            let title = try titles[i].text()
            print(title)
            print("")
        }
    }
}
```

Now above I need to assign what is in the title to an array outside of the class. So I created a variable (which could be wrong and maybe that is the issue):

```
var discussionTitles = [String?]()
```

My viewController is named LoginController. Now I tried adding this to the DiscussionBoardResponse to assign titles to the variable:

```
class DiscussionBoardResponse {

    //let discussionTopics: [DiscussionTopicSingle]
    init(_ innerHTML: Any?) throws {
    guard let htmlString = innerHTML as? String else { throw HTMLError.badInnerHTML }
        let doc = try SwiftSoup.parse(htmlString)
        let titles = try doc.getElementsByClass("Forum_NormalBold").array()

        var nestedLoginController: LoginController!
        for i in 0..<titles.count {
            let title = try titles[i].text()
            //tried converting title into a string in case it was't
            //guard let titleString = title as? String else { return }
            nestedLoginController?.discussionTitles[i] = title
            print(nestedLoginController?.discussionTitles[i])
            print("")
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I print the nestedLoginController?.discussionTitles[I] It only prints out nil for every title. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: Im now rethinking a little on how to do this because the other way is not working, so inside where I click the button which takes me to DiscussionBoardResponse looks like this:

```
do {
    let discussionResponse = try DiscussionBoardResponse(innerLoginHTML)
    print("Got Response")
} catch{}
```

I attempt to send over the variable discussionTitles

```
let discussionResponse = try DiscussionBoardResponse(innerLoginHTML, test: self.discussionTitles)
```

and in the DiscussionResponse I have now:

```
init(_ innerHTML: Any?, test: [String] = []) throws {
    guard let htmlString = innerHTML as? String else { throw HTMLError.badInnerHTML }
        let doc = try SwiftSoup.parse(htmlString)
        let titles = try doc.getElementsByClass("Forum_NormalBold").array()
        //var nestedLoginDelete: [String] = []
        for i in 0..<titles.count {
            let title = try titles[i].text()
            test.append(title) 
        }
    }
}
```

and I now get the error: Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'test' is a 'let' constant. Im not sure even if this worked is im actually manipulating the variable discussionTitles or if im just manipulating some instance of it? Either way what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `nestedLoginController` is declared but has no value. And `discussionTitles[i]` will crash reliably if the array is empty.

Comment: It's strange logic to have a variable declared as force unwrapped with `!` and also test it for nil with `?`.

Comment: @vadian how or what do I declare to nestedLoginController since its only used to describe a class using nestedLoginController.variableInsideOfClass?

Comment: You have to assign the real `LoginController` instance to the variable `nestedLoginController` to have access to its properties.

Comment: @PhillipMills "It's strange logic to have a variable declared as force unwrapped with `!` and also test it for nil with `?`." No, it isn't. It's a standard way to get the combination of delayed initialization and the convenience of not having to unwrap all over the place.

Comment: You never initialise the `nestedLoginController`, so you will get a nil return not because any contents of the `titles` array is nil, but because you are optional chaining from a nil object.  However as said vadian said you have greater problems and probably need to rearchitect the solution

Comment: are you saying I should do init(nestedLoginController: LoginController!). Im not quite sure what you mean other than that. And when I add super. in front I get this error: 'super' members cannot be referenced in a root class

Comment: @matt Don't agree.  It's saying, "This variable will *always* have a value before it's referenced...but maybe not."  `if let` scopes may be more verbose but are clear and explicit.

Comment: @flanker what do I add set nestedLoginController equal too? if I already have var nestedLoginController: LoginController! then after that I assume I would put nestedLoginController = something, but since LoginController is a class I don't know what it should be equal too?

Comment: @PhillipMills I do it when I know I have delayed intialization, e.g. we segue to this view controller, it shows its interface, and now in the background I start gathering the data. I'll be using this data a _lot_ and I don't want to have `?` or `if let` _all_ over the place, but there is a danger I'll access it before it's populated so I can `guard` against that with `nil` tests. Can we agree that we disagree over _style_ rather than _logic_?

Comment: @TheRetroGamer all you have done is declared you want to have a variable for the login controller, you haven't actually set it equal to anything.  Until you actually set that variable with an instance of the class it just an empty pointer.  How you do that it's hard to say as the architecture seems back-to-front.